# GO - Golang AES128 ECB Decryption

Tags: go, cryptography

I find the snippet of the code from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072026/golang-aes-ecb-encryption/71614065?noredirect=1#comment126568172_71614065](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)in golang to decrypts AES-128 data in ECB (note that the block size is 16 bytes):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
)

func DecryptAes128Ecb(data, key []byte) []byte {
    cipher, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
    decrypted := make([]byte, len(data))
    size := 16

    for bs, be := 0, size; bs < len(data); bs, be = bs+size, be+size {
        cipher.Decrypt(decrypted[bs:be], data[bs:be])
    }

    return decrypted
}
```

- But I am unable to understand it. I tried to search  full code online but I no luck.
- Can someone provide the full code or explain it.
- Sorry, I am new to golang

I tried to search online but was unable to get the full code and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind that ECB [is insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB)) and must not be used for real encryption.  That being said, here is what the code does line by line:

```
cipher, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
```

This returns a new object which has [methods to perform AES encryption/decryption](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#Block), using the given key.

```
decrypted := make([]byte, len(data))
```

This allocates space to hold the decrypted result.  The length is the same as the length of the input.

```
size := 16
```

This is the block size of the AES cipher in bytes.  We could also have written `size := cipher.BlockSize()` here.  The length of the input must be a multiple of 16 bytes.

```
for bs, be := 0, size; bs < len(data); bs, be = bs+size, be+size { ... }
```

This iterates over the 16 byte blocks in the input.  The first block has start `bs = 0` and end `be = size`, and the we just add 16 to both `bs` and `be` repeatedly to get all the other blocks.

```
cipher.Decrypt(decrypted[bs:be], data[bs:be])
```

This uses the `cipher` object we created at the start to decrypt a single block.  The input is `data[bs:be]` and the output is stored in `decrypted[bs:be]`.  After the loop is finished, the slice `decrypted` contains the decrypted cleartext.

Answer (score -1):

So the code answer to how to do ECB encryption is as follows:

```
import (
  "crypto/aes"
)
func normalizePhoneNumber(phoneNumber string) ([]byte){
   // Convert phone number into a standard form such as:
   // +19123457890
   // then with normalBytes
   block := make([]byte, 16)
   copy(block, normalBytes)
   return block
}
func getKey()([]byte){
   // TODO implement get 256 bit key
}

// People say ECB is insecure but sometimes it's the best option,
// Certainly for de-anonymizing phone numbers it's better than hashing
func Encode(phoneNumber string) (enc []byte, err error) {
   enc = normalizePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
   keyBytes := getKey()
   encrypted := make([]byte, 16)
   cipher, err := aes.NewCipher(keyBytes)
   if err != nil{
     return
   }
   // since enc overlaps enc entirely this does
   // an in place encryption.
   cipher.encrypt(enc, enc)
   return
}
```

I will leave the opinionating to others, but IMHO sometimes ECB is just the ticket particularly if you are keeping a database of phone numbers that need the equality property preserved which ECB is ideal for and if that database is keyed by phone number the hacker will find it a whole lot harder to de-anonymize than if they had a list of hashed phone numbers.  At least not unless they get the encryption key.

Comment: I can see that some folks have strong opinions and are not afraid to burn 10 (anonymously) of their own reputation to burn one of mine. But apparently afraid to leave an explanatory comment. Good job! By the way regarding ECB being insecure. It's insecure for large texts, but for a single block it is a useful way to achieve anonymization via deterministic hashing.  The only reason its considered insecure is that patterns in the data spanning more than one block are easily discernable.  But for any data inside a single block the only thing it leaks is equality.  For indexed data this is ideal.